# Having trouble creating JPA mapping with MYSQL Table structure

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a table that models a relationship where a country can support multiple pitch types. So US supports pitch types 1, 2, and 3. MX supports pitch types 2, 3, and 4.

The `pitch_type` table is a simple key-value with a pitch_type_id referencing a string value. The table that joins types to country codes is here:

```
CREATE TABLE `country_pitch` (
  `country_pitch_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_code` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `pitch_type_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`country_pitch_id`),
  INDEX `fk_country_code_to_pitch_type_id_idx` (`pitch_type_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_country_code_to_pitch_type_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pitch_type_id`)
    REFERENCES `pitch_type` (`pitch_type_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

yielding:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| country_pitch_id | country_code | pitch_type_id |
---------------------------------------------------
| 1                | us           | 1             |
| 2                | us           | 2             |
| 3                | us           | 3             |
| 4                | mx           | 2             |
| 5                | mx           | 3             |
| 6                | mx           | 4             |
---------------------------------------------------
```

`country_pitch_id` is not used and the important concept is matching a country code to its associated pitch_type.

I believe this would best be represented by a ManyToMany relationship as a country can have multiple pitch types and a pitch type can belong to multiple countries. My goal is to model this in a POJO similar to this:

```
/**
 * For a given market, US, CA, MX, etc, identify the available reach
 * generation curve types
 */
@Entity(name = "country_pitch")
@Data
public class CountryPitchTypes {
    public CountryPitchTypes() {}

    @Column(name = "country_code")
    private String countryCode;

    @ElementCollection
    @Convert(converter = PitchTypeConverter.class)
    private List<PitchType> pitchTypes;
}
```

but this mapping doesn't work out of the box because I'm trying to map a join table to this entity so I get `Unknown column` errors. Can you guide me to what the proper addition to the pojo would be to map this table to a single pojo with the associated list?

I feel like a @JoinTable annotation is necessary with some sort of grouping but not sure how to configure it. At the end of the day, **I'm trying to map the country_pitch table to the CountryPitchTypes class, grouping all the pitch types by country code.**

Country codes are not part of our db, btw. That is, there is no `countries` table where a country_id num points to the 2-letter country_code.

Comment: `Country codes are not part of our db, btw.`  you mean you can remove it from `country_pitch` table ?

Comment: No, just that there is no "countries" table mapping the code to an id.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation ManyToMany is incorrect in this case. It means many of CountryPitchTypes map to many of PitchType. What you need here is OneToMany.

Comment: Or you can a ManyToMany relationship of Countries and Pitches and have hibernate figure out the rest. It will automatically generate the bridge table for you to resolve the ManyToMany relationship.

Comment: I updated the example to use both OneToMany and ElementCollection, but it is still not working

Comment: What is the issue that you are seeing when you change to OneToMany? How are you using this relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Since the country code can be mapped to n pitch types and a single pitch type can be mapped to n countries 
So we have a ManyToMany relationship

You have 2 ways implementing ManyToMany relationship either using composite primary key using the 2 relational columns or using a single primary id alongside with the 2 relational columns just as you are doing with `country_pitch_id` so following all this entity should be as follows:

```
@Entity(name = "country_pitch")
@Data
public class CountryPitchTypes {
    public CountryPitchTypes() {}

    @Id
    @Column(name = "country_pitch_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) // or whatever strategy you see good
    private Long countryPitchId

    @Column(name = "country_code")
    private String countryCode;

    @JoinColumn(name = "pitch_type_id", referencedColumnName = "pitch_type_id")
    @ManyToOne
    @Convert(converter = PitchTypeConverter.class)
    private PitchType pitchType;
}
```

Now you can go do something like

```
SELECT cpt.pitchType from CountryPitchTypes cpt group by cpt.countryCode;
```

**Side Note**
Remember that ManyToMany relation is basically creating a third table `country_pitch` where you have ManyToOne fields to another table `pitch_type` that has OneToMany of this third table so you can now update `PitchType` entity to have OneToMany of `CountryPitch` but you won't use this anyway so one of relationship is sufficient this BTW is what is called a *unidirectional relation*.

In JPA @ManyToMany annotation is used when the third table does not has any extra columns `country_pitch_id` just the 2 relational columns that way JPA implicitly understands that the table is used to do ManyToMany relationship, You can then use @ManyToMany on the related entities without creating the 3rd entity.

Comment: Not sure I understand, are you saying mapping to a List<PitchType> is not possible and that I need to refactor to a single PitchType? I think my initial example was unclear... using the countryPitchId would not be necessary/feasible as I'm looking to map multiple rows to a sngle entity, grouping by country code.

Comment: Yes you need to refactor your code `country_pitch` table aka the owner of the  relationship thus entity `CountryPitchTypes` follows the same idea having only one single reference to `PitchType` as `ManyToOne` side of the relationship

Comment: `I'm looking to map multiple rows to a single entity, grouping by country code` You can do this simply by inserting  multiple `country_code` values with the same `pitch_type_id`